# How to use props in helper functions in React

Tags: reactjs

I want to use the data from props in the helper function as a parameter.

However, I still can't do it, I tried directly

```
const SuperHero = (props) => {
  const [hero, setHero] = useState("");

  const searchSuperHero = (props.name) => {}
```

Also using destructuring props

```
const SuperHero = (props) => {
  const [hero, setHero] = useState("");
  const {name} = props.name;

  const searchSuperHero = (name) => {}
```

But I still can't capture the data and it shows the variable as declared but never used even though it is used right in the function below.

Please, Where is problem?

Thank you

Comment: You need to call the helper function passing the parameter, e.g: `searchSuperHero(props.name)` make sure the name is coming in the props

Answer (score 1):

Both of your code blocks are incorrect for the same reason: defining argument parameters.

```js
const SuperHero = (props) => {
  const [hero, setHero] = useState("");

  const searchSuperHero = (props.name) => {} // you're trying to define a parameter called props.name for your new function
```

Try this:

```
const SuperHero = (props) => {
  const [hero, setHero] = useState("");

  const searchSuperHero = () => {
    console.log(props.name);
  } 
}
```

Also, it's unrelated to your question, but the correct syntax for destructuring an object is:

```
const { name } = props;
```

destructuring plucks out the chosen value so you don't need to use `.`

Comment: Thank you for nice explanation, you saved my day.